# Passing a values/arguments to Shell Script with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Below is a shell script for taking 2 input parameter values,

1. `asd#@#g#@#h#@#j@#@k`
2. candidateid

which gives us output as

```
string0 asd
string1 g
string2 h 
.
.
.

candidateid

.
.
.
```

(& then both parameters are used in Oracle queries)

Now the problem is that the above code fails when I try to pass 1st parameter with spaces.

eg: `/TOM/Process Folders/System Drive/a.jpg`

The above given location should be considered as 1st string.
If I give the above within Double Quotes, then it works fine.
But the above parameter that I am getting is without quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1

input1=$2

IFS='#' read -a arr <<< "${input//#@#/#}"

for((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++))
do
        echo "String$i ${arr[i]}"
done

read passportphotos <<< "${arr[0]}"
read academiccertificates <<< "${arr[1]}"
read dateofbirth <<< "${arr[2]}"
read addressproof <<< "${arr[3]}"
read pancard <<< "${arr[4]}"
read pfnominationform <<< "${arr[5]}"
read gratuitynomination <<< "${arr[6]}"
read investmentdeclaration <<< "${arr[7]}"
read resignationletter <<< "${arr[8]}"
read acceptanceoffer <<< "${arr[9]}"
read acceptancecodeofconduct <<< "${arr[10]}"
read medicalnomination <<< "${arr[11]}"
read backgroungverification <<< "${arr[12]}"
read personaldataform <<< "${arr[13]}"

echo $passportphotos
echo $academiccertificates
echo $dateofbirth
echo $addressproof
echo $pancard
echo $pfnominationform
echo $gratuitynomination
echo $investmentdeclaration
echo $resignationletter
echo $acceptanceoffer
echo $acceptancecodeofconduct
echo $medicalnomination
echo $backgroungverification
echo $personaldataform

instant_client="/root/ora_client/instantclient_11_2"
view=`$instant_client/sqlplus -s HRUSER/HRUSER@TOMLWF <<EOF

set heading off

set feedback off

set lines 10000

set pagesize 10000


insert into EMPLOYEEDOCUMENTS VALUES ((SELECT EMPLOYEEID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE CANDIDATEID='$input1'),'Resume','Doc','$passportphotos','Y','HR',(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL),'HR',(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL),'HR',(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL));
`

echo $view
```

Comment: What you mean by `"But the above parameter that i am getting is without qoutes"`? How are you invoking the script that you cannot add the quotes around it?

Comment: the above code needs 2 parameter to execute.

Comment: If you want to provide a parameter with spaces, you have to quote it.

Comment: i am getting the parameters from a tool. & i am running script .... simply ... sh script.sh parameter1 parameter2

Comment: Please show the exact code of how you're getting the parameters and passing them to the script. Edit it into your question.

Comment: yes ... i get you point barmar. but i have no control to put qoutes onto the parameter before running the script. Inside the code, i can put qoutes.

Comment: Then the tool that runs your script is broken. It needs to quote all the parameters, there's no way for the script to do this by itself. It should be `sh script.sh 'parameter1' 'parameter2'`.

Comment: If you want me to see future comments, don't forget to put "@barmar" in them, so I'll be notified.

Comment: @Barmar:  sh delimiter_new.sh company_home/TOM/Proc_joingchecklist_test/Process Instance Documents/Instance.jpg 14492 . Here i am passing 2 varibles,the 1st one is company_home/TOM/Proc_joingchecklist_test/Process Instance Documents/Instance.jpg while the second one is 14492. The script should ideally the 1st parameter as a whole & second 14492 as the other parameter. But it breaks the 1st in two parameter wherever it gets spaces.

Comment: @Venkatesh as I said in my edit, you must either add the quotes, or find an adequate separator to your command line arguments

Comment: @Rubens: can u please show me it with an example. suppose i have string as:-  apple#@#mango#@#guava  #@#grape.

Comment: @Rubens: there is space between guava & #@#grape. but is one whole string

Comment: @Venkatesh what I mean is that, if you really cannot use quotes in your command line call, you must determine a new separator; considering `between guava & #@#grape` as your string, you must be able to say, either that after each pair of whitespaces you'll have an argument, or that your arguments are separated by the `&`, which would give you `arg1=between guava ` and `arg2= #@#grape`

Comment: @Rubens: Thanks a ton for the hint that you gave. & yes its working. Now i will have to write two scripts. One scripts that takes all watever is passed after it as whole one argument, & then convert all the spaces with underscores. & finally then my script which will do the needy :)

Comment: @Venkatesh i'll add this reading with `&` to my post.

Comment: @Rubens: I hope you now understood.. wat sort of technical problems i was facing. Please do vote up my question. It was indeed a tricky one to answer :)

Comment: @Venkatesh it was not I to vote down your post; you must be clear on what you are asking. Anyway, what do you want as an answer, then? Do you want to convert spaces with underscores, but how are you suppose to extract the arguments?

Comment: @Rubens:Actually .. i have a tool which is throwin me number of arguments(specific locations) with #@# as a delimiter between each. So i wrote a code to separate them all & insert them all(specific locations) with a particular id into database. That's why i was using 2 arguments in code. But then i realized that there were spaces in between the arguments which was breaking my code. so i came up with such question.

Comment: @Rubens:I would extract the arguments intially with IFS=' ' read -a arr <<< "${argument//_spaces_/_underscore_}" .This would turn the whole argument to one continuous 1 without spaces. & then i would user IFS='#' read -a arr <<< "${argument//#@#/#}" . I hope u understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you did not really have to post all of that code to say you're in trouble with spaces in an argument.

As a complement, in any programming language, it's rather much more useful to use an array, or to map values into a container — using an associative array, in case of bash — than creating dozens of variables.

*Edit*:

I'm sorry; as pointed by Barmar, I misread the post, and I presented something that does really changes not the execution of your program. Fact is that, if the problem is with the command line argument, then you must include double quotes wrapping it; this is how the arguments are read.

You can, though, read all the arguments into an array, and then change the `IFS`, just as you did. Pay attention to the fact that your arguments must be separated by something already known at hand, as well as in your usage of `IFS='#'`.

Comment: u really arent gettin my point. try executin the code first & then put your views please. Its a run time argument. It still breaks the the argument wherever it gets spaces.

Comment: would you mind to point out what is the `first code` in your question? people are here to help, not to find out your intentions from within your posts

Comment: Quotes aren't needed in assignment statements like this, so it won't fix it.

Comment: @rubens: i am getting the parameters from a tool. & i am running script .... simply ... sh script.sh parameter1 parameter2. here parameter1 consists of spaces while parameters doesn't.

Comment: thanks, Barmar, I noticed my mistake; Venkatesh, i've made an edit, please, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke your script this way:

```
delimiter_new.sh 'company_home/TOM/Proc_joingchecklist_test/Process Instance Documents/Instance.jpg' 14492
```

You need to put quotes around the filename so it will be treated as a single argument.

Also, you don't need to specify `sh` explicitly, the `#!/bin/bash` line in the script tells the OS to run bash.

Comment: You many need to specify `sh` or `bash` in case the file does not have execute permissions

Comment: @another.anon.coward Fix the permissions.

Comment: @Barmer: yes barmer. i am already aware of this one. but i cant put quotes around the filename. i am getting the argument from a tool which is just passing me the file location. because i dont have the control do it. I can just pass watever i am getting from the tool.

Comment: Ofc :) (... Probably make little sense to have a shell script without execute permission )

Comment: How are you getting it from the tool? Is it in a variable? Then put double quotes around the variable. Or is your tool running your script ? In that case, it's what I said above -- the tool has a bug if it doesn't quote the arguments, because there's no way for your script to tell that a filename with spaces should be just one argument.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks a ton for your help. With some hint from Rubens, yes its working. Now i will have to write two scripts. One scripts that takes all watever is passed after it as whole one argument, & then convert all the spaces with underscores. & finally then my script which will do the needy :)